# cgi scripts with python

Tags: python, cgi

I tries to run a cgi-script using this as server in python3:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler

port = 8080

httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
print("Starting simple_httpd on port: " + str(httpd.server_port))
httpd.serve_forever()
```

but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/http/server.py", line 1110, in run_cgi
    os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
localhost - - [21/Nov/2012 10:28:26] CGI script exit status 0x7f00
```

Please Help.

Comment: Notice the error: `No such file or directory`. Check whether the file is there or not.

Comment: Can you let us know what's there in line `1110`. Paste the content of that line here.

Comment: With the default settings if you are accessing hello.py then the file must be located as cgi-bin/hello.py . cgi-bin is a directory parallel to your server

Comment: This is what is in line 1110:`os.execve(scriptfile, args, env)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hope these help:
1. check whether the script you are going to execute is executable? if it is not -rwx, it can not be execute
2. check the the top line of the script, i.e., #! ..... if this line does not correctly point to the folder of your python, it still can not be execute

Comment: The path to the python binary was the problem in my case - really irritating that the error message states that the python file isn't there instead!